# EF Code-First Migration - Ignore Property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a simple poco class that has an enum property (Needed so that I can still have the code first create the enum lookup table).  I don't want the migration generator to add this column to the database.  Is there an attribute or some other way to let the migration code know to ignore the property?

Example:

```
public class MyPoco
{
    public int MyPocoId { get; set; }
    public int MyPocoTypeId { get; set; }

    public MyPocoTypeEnum MyPocoTypeEnum
    {
        get { return (MyPocoTypeEnum)MyPocoTypeId; }
        set { MyPocoTypeId = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use NotMappedAttribute

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.notmappedattribute(v=vs.103).aspx

Or I prefer to use fluent mapping as it doesn't clutter my domain model with data access concerns.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyPoco>().Ignore(p => p.MyPocoTypeEnum);
```

Comment: Excellent, I will give it a try.  I can modify the Mapping.tt file to add those to the map and keep the POCO clean.

Comment: when I use FluentMApping, the field is still returned in the resultset, albeit it NULL know. How do I get it to not even be returned?